# Bootstrap v 4.1.3 - navbar placing items

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a problem -  i am trying to separate the navbar-brand and the rest. I would like to have the logo- so the navbar-brand and the left and all of the menu items on the right side of the menu, I have tried using flex like it is said in the bootstrap documentation but I cant achieve want i want :)

Please help :P

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale =1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Wordpress first site</title>
  <!-- ==================== BOOTSTRAP CSS ==================== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- ==================== FONTAWESOME ICONS ==================== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <!-- ==================== GOOGLE FONTS ==================== -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <!-- ==================== HEADER ==================== -->
  <header>
    <div class="container" role="navigation">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-flex justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </nav>

    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- ==================== HERO ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== OPT IN SECTION  ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== BOOST UR INCOME ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== WHO BENEFITS SECTION ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== FEATURES ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== PROJECT FEATURES ==================== -->
  <section> </section>
  <!-- ==================== VIDEOS ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== ABOUT ME ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== TESTIMONIALS ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== SIGN UP ==================== -->
  <section></section>
  <!-- ==================== FOOTER ==================== -->
  <footer></footer>
  <!-- ==================== MODAL ==================== -->
  <div></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex justify-content-end">`! `ml-auto` if you want it to be pushed to the right side.

Comment: add an `id` to the items you want on the left and another `id` for the right side and style with `position:relative;`, `left:0`, `right:0`. or just wrap 1 div around the left side and one around the right side and use CSS Flexbox on the `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale =1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Wordpress first site</title>
    <!-- ==================== BOOTSTRAP CSS ==================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ==================== FONTAWESOME ICONS ==================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <!-- ==================== GOOGLE FONTS ==================== -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shiv and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<!-- ==================== HEADER ==================== -->
<header>
    <div class="container" role="navigation">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="position:relative">
          
            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="position:absolute;right:10px;">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```